# An elaboration of Thm. 8.11(c) proof.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

The theorem is given below[image] :

And the book said that the proof of $(c)$ should be apparent but my proof to it was as follows:

Since the index definition is given by $r^{\operatorname{ind} a} \equiv a \pmod n$, then upon substituting $a = 1$ in this formula we get $r^{\operatorname{ind} 1}  \equiv 1 \pmod n$, which means that $\operatorname{ind} 1 = 0 \pmod n $ but I need it to be $\operatorname{ind} 1 = 0 \pmod {\phi(n)} $  instead, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The order of $r$ is $\phi(n)$. So, you have $\operatorname{ind} 1=0\bmod (\phi(n))$.

Comment: Could you please see this question please (if you have time ) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253718/an-elaboration-of-how-an-index-formula-comes-from-another-formula  @JulianMejia

Comment: @JulianMejia could you clarify more please? I do not understand your first comment ...... you mean in our case $\phi (1) = 1$ which means $\phi (n) = n$?

Comment: I am saying that you may not have the correct definition of primitive root, because $r^m\equiv 1\pmod n$ does not imply $n|m$. I posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (sub)group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is the group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times=\{\overline{a}:\gcd(a,n)=1\}$. This group has $\phi(n)$ elements.

A number $r$ is called a primitive root if $\overline{r}$ is a generator of this group $\left(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$, this is the same as saying that the order of $r$ mod $n$ is $\phi(n)$ (i.e. if $r^{m}\equiv 1\pmod n$, then $\phi(n)|m$).

So, when you have $r^{\operatorname{ind} 1}\equiv 1\bmod n$, this implies that $\phi(n)|\operatorname{ind} 1$.

Comment: why $\phi (n) | ind 1$ implies that ind 1 = 0?

Comment: $\phi(n)|ind(1)$ implies $ind(1)=0\pmod{ \phi(n)}$